Installing and configuring ZeroTier application in TrueNAS
How to properly set up ZeroTier in the TrueNAS Scale server to access the NAS server through the ZT network? I have installed ZT and confirmed that it is connected through the pod shell. However, I am encountering two issues:

Even if the ZT in TrueNAS is online, the server dashboard and services are not exposed. What are the actual steps required to make this work?
The ZT application is creating new members continuously, which has resulted in over 500 connections in my ZeroTier dashboard. How can I prevent this from happening?




Even if the ZT in TrueNAS is online, the server dashboard and services are not exposed. What are the actual steps required to make this work?

You will most likely need to enable the "Host Network" option in the zerotier app settings. Click Edit on zerotier and enable it there, then restart zerotier.

The ZT application is creating new members continuously, which has resulted in over 500 connections in my ZeroTier dashboard. How can I prevent this from happening?

For some reason (probably due to how it's virtualized) the ZeroTier TrueNAS SCALE App refuses to store its own configuration making it not plug-and-play like other apps. What you need to do is manually create an identity as such:

Open the Shell for the application (The Shell icon under Workloads)
Run zerotier-idtool generate identity.secret identity.public
Copy the contents of the identity.secret and identity.public files to the app configuration page (Click edit on zerotier, then add that as Identity Secret and Identity Public)

Credit for this to TasmanSkies on Reddit
Chances are once you have this all set up the app will still be stuck at Deploying but work, it seems to be an issue with the app.

Just wanted to give an update for anyone still looking now:
On the latest version of Truenas (ElectricEel 24.10) which now just uses plain Docker containers instead of Kubernetes, I submitted an issue to update the container to use storage by default.
This should fix the playing around with identity.secret and identity.public needed in the past, and you can just install the container with the network ID, authorize it, and be on your way. 
